# Including Visualforce Site pages in Site.com

Tags: visualforce, site.com

Is there an option to add `visualforce page` to the `Site.com Site pages`? I am trying to add a Custom Visualforce page form in the Site .com,  however I could not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No,

Site.com sites exist outside the flow of your Apex code and VF pages. So the answer is no, you're not able to use Apex code or VisualForce tags inside of Site.com.

Site.com is a content management system that enables easy creation and management of a website's content. There is access to SFDC data through Data Repeaters and Data Connections. You can also create forms and web-to-lead interactivity through Site.com. And you have full use of front-end code, such as JavaScript and CSS.